# Do I need to know spring framework before beginning with spring data neo4j?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

This is for a college project. The professor told we need to use neo4j for graph database and since POJOs cannot be stored as nodes in neo4j, we will need to use spring data too. Sounded good enough. When I actually got down coding, the tutorials I came across were way over my head. The sample code made use of annotations, xml, beans and whatnot without any explanation as to where they come from. I assume they are all a part of spring framework which I have no experience with. So how much spring will I need to learn before thinking of spring neo4j? I cannot ask help from my professor since he is the management type of guy who knows all the words like technologies but has no  idea how they work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not know to learn everything there is to know about Spring.

I would recommend downloading the examples from [github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples) and play with them, for a start.

I also recommend this [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heC-8Pq2exQ&feature=youtu.be) on YouTube.

It is also worth mentioning that you *do not need Spring* to map back and forth betwheen nodes and POJOS.  [This page in the manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8/tutorials-java-embedded-entities.html) shows a much sampler way of doing it.

Comment: That does seem like a much simpler way of doing things. Will see how it goes. Thanks!